# How to send input values in android to d1mini wifi controller through wifi?

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip, wifi-direct

I'm working on a app which will create hotspot when it opens, after opening the app user have to send user name and password to connected deceives , let say if i have a d1mini wifi controller which is connected to hotspot, i need to send the input values to d1mini, i tried wifip2p and socket programming but both wont work!

please any one help me how to send input values to hardware devices through wifi!